# Is there a version of GNU indent which supports Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, indentation

If so where can I get it?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170601/objective-c-tidy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) seems to be useful. I haven't tested it yet.

[Here](http://github.com/andreberg/uncrustify) is a brach that claims

> Code beautifier and a very mighty one at that.
>   This fork aims to improve support for Objective-C/Objective-C++.

[Here](http://github.com/andreberg/uncrustify/blob/master/etc/objc.cfg) you'll find a config for objC.

[This blogpost](http://www.invasivecode.com/blog/archives/934) describes how to run uncrustify from xcode