# objective-c source code formatter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-formatting, textwrangler

I prefer something that will work with Xcode 4, but I need a pretty print formatter for Objective-C code on the mac.  I have tried Editor > Structure > Re-indent, but nothing happens (I have the code string selected beforehand).  I am happy to use that if someone can tell me how to get it to work.  The Preferences > Text Editing > Indentation is set to default settings, but I've tried changing these too.

So... I have looked all over but not found a tool to do this simple task for me.  Text Wrangler says it will do it, but again nothing happens when I try to format the code.

May certainly be user error, but I need help - I'm tired of hand formatting the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example](http://www.invasivecode.com/blog/archives/934) for Xcode 3.  I don't have Xcode 4 so I can't test it there, but hopefully something similar will work.  If not, you could create a service with Automator.

Also see these questions:

- [Objective-C Tidy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170601/objective-c-tidy)
- [Is there a version of GNU indent which supports Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849418/is-there-a-version-of-gnu-indent-which-supports-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks - the article looks promising... I had looked at crustify before but seemed too much pain for something that should be simple!

Comment: Do file a bug on Xcode too. Xcode 4 is just at the beginning of its life, as the first version with real language awareness and it may be something that is causing the reformatter not to behave as designed.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Uncrustify tool](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/). Works for me when I've got a bad formatted code =)

Also, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561474/objective-c-style-formatter) question.