# Xcode indenting an html/javascript file

Tags: javascript, xcode

So I am editing a HTML file with a bunch of javascript in it that I am using in my iOS project. Xcode is doing a terrible job of letting me indent things. Is there any way to mess with the indentation settings at all? Things are just getting really hard to read.

[image]

Comment: Don't copy and paste this code in Xcode. Edit this code in any other compatible editor and then simply drag and drop that file into Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

There's a preference in Xcode for this.

[image: Indentation Preferences]

This will likely *not* help the text currently in the files you're editing (since the indentations / spaces are already there and to change them, you need to do some manual editing), but modifying these preferences will help you going forward.

Also, [here's a related question with answers that may help you further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658296/how-to-setup-xcode-for-proper-javascript-formatting).

Comment: Actually, you can highlight the text, right-click, and choose Something I Forgot > Re-Indent

Comment: The "Structure" submenu. Nice catch!

Comment: Yep. Pretty useful when one of those `if` statements inside a completion block combined with a missing semicolon somewhere confuses Xcode, causing it to think everything is a `pragma` statement :)